# cannot remove searchController when switching between childViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a container viewController with two childViewControllers.  Both childViewControllers are tableViewControllers.  I want only one of the child viewControllers to be able to use a searchController.

I define and setup the searchController in the viewDidLoad of the parent containerViewController as such:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.delegate = self.childOneTableViewController
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self.childOneTableViewController
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

I am using a segmented control to switch between the two childViewControllers.

What I want to do is hide the searchBar for the second childViewController but so far I can only achieve that by setting the searchController to nil which is not something I want to do.

I have read many posts that highlight what to do when segueing but this is a slightly different scenario.

I thought the obvious thing was: searchController.isActive = false when adding the secondChildViewController:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            remove(asChildViewController: childOneTableViewController)
            add(asChildViewController: childTwoTableViewController)
            navigationItem.searchController!.isActive = true
        } else {
            remove(asChildViewController: childOneTableViewController)
            add(asChildViewController: childTwoTableViewController)
            navigationItem.searchController!.isActive = false
        }
    }
```

however this is having no effect and the searchController remains visible in both childViewControllers

Answer (score 2):

The search bar will remain visible on both child view controllers because you set it to be the navigation item of the parent controller. To hide the search bar for the second child controller you can do the following in your else statement: `searchController.searchBar.hidden = true`

Activating the search controller doesn't show or hide the search bar, it affects whether or not the search results view controller is presented. More on that [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618659-isactive).

Comment: thanks.  understand your point about activating now.  the problem with searchBar.isHidden = true is that when you pull down on the tableView the navigationBar expands by the amount of the searchBar frame downward which is not ideal.  I think the only thing I can do is to set the searchController to nil.